# Animated background image by buttons

Tags: jquery, animation, button, background

Sorry if this question has been done to death already but I'm having trouble animating a background image. I've attached the relevant background pluggin and I can get it to animate as a one button manouver but I'm struggling to get several buttons all to have their own background position point on the same image.

The aim is to have a banner image animate to different points as each link is clicked.

Here's my code so far:

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('#banner').animate({backgroundPosition:'(-400px 0px)'},500);
    } //end Home banner animation

    $('#releases').click(function(){
        $('#banner').animate({backgroundPosition:'(-800px 0px)'},500);
    } // end releases banner animation
} //end ready
```

I'm fairly new to Jquery, I understand the basics but this is a bit of a head scratch for me. Their are plenty of tutorials on background animations but I can't find one that does quite this.

Comment: You don't have closing parentheses on the click handlers: `click(function(){ ... });` Or on the `ready` function for that matter.

Comment: try something like: `$('#banner').stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '-400px 0px'},500);` no `()` in the css asignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your jquery code here.

- No braces around document
- No ending braces
- backgroundPostition should be background-position

Another problem I encountered was using the background-postion and setting x & y coordinates at the same time. For now I changed it to use background-position-x & digging why that doesn't work.
Here is a working code that might help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('#banner').animate({'background-position-x' : '-400px'},500);
    }); //end Home banner animation

    $('#releases').click(function(){
        $('#banner').animate({'background-position-x' :'-800px'},500);
    }); // end releases banner animation
}); //end ready
```

Comment: Thats great help, I will look back at my code and correct my errors. Thanks a buddle.